# How to use a where clause with in a PageRequest in Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I got lost trying to filter a PageRequest

I have my Object StatusUpdate with an attribute that can be null:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="group_id", nullable=true)
private Group group;
```

I have my Controller:

```
Page<StatusUpdate> page = statusUpdateService.getPage(pageNumber);
```

And the Service I would like to modify:

```
    public Page<StatusUpdate> getPage(int pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber-1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "added");
    return statusUpdateDao.findAll(request);
}
```

And I would like to modify it so it can Page the results as it is doing now, but not including those where my attribute Group is NULL.

How can I include a filter in my....: PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber-1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "added")? I would like to have it there... I need to see an example (and I can not find it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this but try

```
@Repository
public interface StatusUpdateDao extends CrudRepository<StatusUpdate, Long> {
     Page<StatusUpdate> findByGroupIsNull(Pageable pageable);
}
```

For more complex queries, I would suggested [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration)